# Pseudo element after is not displayed on the page

Tags: html, css

Аor some reason the pseudo element is not displayed, although everything seems to be written correctly. Here is my code:

```css
.nav-icon {
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.nav-text {
    font-weight: 400;
}

.nav-container:hover > .nav-text {
    font-weight: 700;
}

.nav-container:hover > .nav-icon::after {
    content: "";
    width: 40px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-container">
    <img class="nav-icon" src="img/nav-1.svg" alt="">
    <div class="nav-text">Campus AI</div>
</div>
```

[image: screen]

Comment: `<img />` tags do not support content at all, let alone `pseudo` elements. You can see this defined at MDN in the technical specs of the element where it mentions ["Permitted Cntent: none (it is a void element)"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#technical_summary)

Answer (score 0):

What is the effect you are hoping to achieve? Displaying a white circle below the icon on hover?

```css
body {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.nav-icon {
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.nav-text {
    font-weight: 400;
}

.nav-container:hover > .nav-text {
    font-weight: 700;
}

.nav-container:hover::after {
    content: "";
    width: 40px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 12px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-container">
    <img class="nav-icon" src="img/nav-1.svg" alt="">
    <div class="nav-text">Campus AI</div>
</div>
```